# How to redirect to the URL entered after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-redirect

I'm working in a WEB project based on ASP.NET and C#. It's not a new project, I'm just fixing some bugs and making some updates.

The website works like, if you're not logged in and write a url depending on the website, it redirects you to the login page. Then, if you login successfully, it redirects you to the opening page.

For instance, let's say "opening.aspx" is the opening page and "vendors.aspx" is another page in the website. If you write "..../projectname/vendors.aspx" to the browser, you're redirected to "..../projectname/login.aspx", then after your login you're redirected to "..../projectname/opening.aspx"

Now, my aim is to redirect the user to the url he wrote, in this example "..../projectname/vendors.aspx" after the successful login. I wrote the code to take the previous page and after the login redirect the user to that page. However, I cannot detect the page which the user tried to enter at the first time. I'm not sure if the project sends the user to the login page with some codes written by the previous programmers or if this is an automatic stuff of asp.net about the default page. While debugging, I always see the requested page as the login page even though I write some other page url to the browser.

What I'm looking for is the place where the requested page is changed into login page instead of the url I wrote. Is this an automatic stuff or should I look for it in the code? If I should look for it in the code, where to look?

Note: The project is based on 3-Tier architecture, with WEB, BUS, DAL and COM layers and WEB pages use user controls in every page instead of login and default.

Answer (score 2):

Typically when asp.net redirects it puts the requested page in the url in the ReturnUrl querystring parameter. You should be able to do something like...

```
if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
    Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
```

If you need to do something special, you could store the original page that is in `ReturnUrl` in something like session or in the database and then redirect after your opening page or what not.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. Now, I have a class like "BasePage" which every page inherits it. So, I though that when I enter a URL, then Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] in Page_Init in that class should return the URL I wrote. However, it returns null. Any idea whereelse to check it?

Comment: well it's likely only on the login page, so how you handle this will need to be there. Since it sounds like you are doing multiple redirects, you will need to store the original ReturnUrl value somewhere like session state or in the query string. I'm guessing you have something like... `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`, you'll want to handle this yourself if you can't use session state and just do something like `Response.Redirect("Opening.aspx?Source=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))`

Comment: Ouw, I've just noticed that the redirection is made in master page and I think I'm gonna be able to manage it now. By the way the code that you wrote didn't work but instead I used Request.Path and then eliminated some parts of it. I have one more question, does Request.Path not return the query string part?

Comment: Yeah I've found it too. Request.Url.Query returns it.

Answer (score 2):

i think u should use cookies and seesion when user logged in user detail saved in cookies

and next time when user enter the url u can check it on masterpage of that pages that cookies are available or not if details available then shoe current url page otherwise redirect on login page